# Repeat timer infinite amount of times

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to add a countdown timer to my Shopify checkout using Google Optimize. I got this to work using the following HMTL & JS. Taken from [here](https://codepen.io/ishanbakshi/pen/pgzNMv)

However once the timer finishes and I reload the page it starts from 17 seconds instead of 5 minutes.

Is there a way to get this to repeat the timer from 5 minutes once it hits 0?

```js
document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
  05 + ":" + 00;
startTimer();


function startTimer() {
  var presentTime = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
  var timeArray = presentTime.split(/[:]+/);
  var m = timeArray[0];
  var s = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
  if(s==59){m=m-1}
  if(m<0){
    return
  }

  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
    m + ":" + s;
  console.log(m)
  setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);

}

function checkSecond(sec) {
  if (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) {sec = "0" + sec}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  if (sec < 0) {sec = "59"};
  return sec;
}
```

```html
<div>Your cart is reserved for <span id="timer"></span></div>
```

If you could give the answer like you are talking to a complete beginner it would be greatly appreciated.

Looks like I have a lot to learn!

Comment: There are certainly ways this could be improved, but I can't see any reason this would ever start from 17 seconds on page-reload.

Comment: Yeah, that part confused me as well. However, I am just looking for a away to repeat this once it hits 0.

Comment: setTimeout() is in my eyes an abuse of the original intention of it. So in your function startTimer() there is a good chance to create an infinity loop on client browsers. Use setInterval() instead. Another advantage of this function is you can write an abort condition.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please provide a [mcve]. `05 + ":" + 00` is not allowed in strict mode. Numbers with leading zeros are octal literals (010 is 8). Because of ambiguity, this was removed in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. This should help out...

```
//JAVASCRIPT
startTimer(5); // SPECIFY AMOUNT OF MINUTES OR NO PARAMETER FOR DEFAULT 5

function startTimer(minutes = 5){
  var timeout = minutes * 60000;
  var ms = timeout;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    ms -= 1000;
    if(ms >= 0) {
      var d = new Date(1000*Math.round(ms/1000)); 
      document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = getMS(d);
    } else {
      startTimer(5); // MAKE TIMER RESTART AGAIN FOR 5 MINS
      // clearInterval(interval); // TO MAKE TIMER STOP UPON REACHING 0:00
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function getMS(d){
  return pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds());
}

function pad(i) { 
  return ('0'+i).slice(-2); 
}
```

```
<!--HTML -->
<body>
<div>Your cart is reserved for <span id="timer"></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however when the timer ends it restarts from 1 hour.

Comment: Alright, i will make an edit...

Comment: Should be good now. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: It's hitting 0 then pausing. Unsure if I am doing something wrong - https://jsfiddle.net/vdo9j3qh/1/

Comment: I have edited the answer again...

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it greatly

Answer (score -1):

In javascript the setInterval function allow you to make anything you want every fixed ms.

```js
interval = setInterval(() => {
              console.log('Waited for 5m');
              // Do whatever you want
              console.log('Waiting for 5m again...');
           }, 300000);

// To stop the interval
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: The asker seems to want their second by second countdown displayed in the DOM, so a single 5 min interval probably doesn't work for them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry to be a pain, how would that look in the javascript I posted above.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp